# SVN checkout Specific folders which has recent commits with respect to a revision in the repository

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

Jenkins job is monitoring a location in SVN where our project resides in different folders. The Size of our project in SVN is 200GB our job checks out the whole project(200GB) every time even for a small modification(50MB). Is there any way to checkout only the folders which are modified with respect to a specific revision so that the load(SVN Checkout) on the Jenkins job is reduced from 200GB to few hundred MB only.
By preserving the working copy in Jenkins work space we only need to run SVN update but it is not possible for some internal reasons.

I know there is no provision for checking out a revision range from SVN repository

I will be very thankful for any kind of suggestions and solutions

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `log -v`:

```
svn log -l1 -v
```

It produces output which contains the list of changed files (in last commit). You can use `grep` to filter the unneeded content: `grep '^   M'` or `sed` to clear the unneeded `M`: `sed -n '/^   M/ s@^   M @@p'`:

```
svn log -l1 -v | sed -n '/^   M/ s@^   M @@p'
```

So you need checkout these files (`svn checkout $(svn log -l1 -v | sed...)`).

Maybe you want expand this solution to new files (`A` sign instead of `M`).

Comment: Thanks uzsolt for your valuable suggestion. What if I have two or more commits in the space of running your command twice can this be achieved with post commit hooks so that I can be notified with only the modified content in last commit.

Comment: svn log -v -r1234:HEAD can rescue me. can this be accomplished using post commit hooks? please give your suggestions I am a beginner in svn

Comment: I think yes. But be carefully: the commit hooks run on server-side!